# Additional mailer service to use the spool and send instant emails in Symfony2 - strange headers

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, spool

by default I use spool mailing solution for sending newsletter in my web page. But I also need to send email immediately. So I have used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270162/how-to-define-an-additional-mailer-service-to-use-the-spool-and-send-instant-ema)

If I send newsletter with Spool everything is fine. But when I use

```
$mailer = $this->get('instant_mailer');
```

I receive email with some text prepend at the beginning:

> HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date: Fri, 07 Sep 2012 16:19:06 GMT

How to remove this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I bet that you're trying to send a Response object.

```
new Response();
```

it goes to __toString ()

```
public function __toString()
{
    $this->prepare();

    return
        sprintf('HTTP/%s %s %s', $this->version, $this->statusCode, $this->statusText)."\r\n".
        $this->headers."\r\n".
        $this->getContent();
}
```

It is because:

```
$this->render('template.html.twig');
```

returns Response to avoid that use:

```
$response = $this->render('template.html.twig');
$text = $response->getContent();
```

Regards,
Max

Comment: If you would bet on it milion bugs, you would be a milioner. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$content = $this->renderView('template.html.twig');
```

instead of

```
$content = $this->render('template.html.twig');
```

render returns a response

Answer (score 0):

Other posible solution to the problem is to use `templating` service instead of `$this->render()`:

```
<?php
$body = $this->get('templating')->render('template.html.twig');
```