# How to define delivery_address for additional mailer server in dev environment?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, swiftmailer

I'm using two swiftmailer services, one as a spool and one for instant mails, as described here [How to define an additional mailer service to use the spool and send instant emails in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270162/how-to-define-an-additional-mailer-service-to-use-the-spool-and-send-instant-ema)


But now my settings in config_dev.yml

```
swiftmailer:
    delivery_address: test@test.com
```

only work for the service using spool.

**Update:** 
So  I looked around on github and found [this](https://github.com/symfony/SwiftmailerBundle/issues/6#issuecomment-15610813), it should be possible but I don't understand how I have to configure my service.

Comment: Have you tried: `instant_mailer.delivery_address: test@test.com`?

Comment: yeah that's not working

Comment: I don't think it's possible. That parameter is part of the configuration of SwiftMailerBundle and not exposed to the service any where I can find.

Comment: When browsing PRs and comments in the Symfony community I don't see evidence that this is truely working. Could you post a sample configuration on how you achieved this if you could? Thank you.